# How to make the appearance of form in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to make a form but it is not showing me. Instead it is giving me error `UnboundLocalError at /withdraw/ local variable 'form' referenced before assignment` How to resolve this issue?

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def withdraw(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Withdrawapayment(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your request has been submitted.')
            return redirect('balance')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'nextone/withdraw.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class WithdrawPayment(models.Model):
    payment = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Withdraw Payment'
```

**forms.py**

```
class Withdrawpayment(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WithdrawPayment
        fields = ['payment']
```

Answer (score 5):

You are handling for `POST` request only so change your view like this:

```
@login_required
def withdraw(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Withdrawapayment(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your request has been submitted.')
            return redirect('balance')
    else:
        form = Withdrawpayemnt()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'nextone/withdraw.html', context)
```